# Firefox just started with proxy server not found

Tags: firefox, proxy

I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 about two months.  For the last couple of days firefox snap keeps saying proxy server not found.  I do not have a proxy server.

The only thing I installed on ubuntu 22.04 was windscribe VPN.

I have tried changing the proxy settings in firefox, I have uninstalled and reinstalled firefox snap, I have tried with VPN on and off.  I do seem to internet connection since I just installed a game(random pick) with appgrid.

Both Opera and Chrome seem to have a problem also, but unsure if they did not make it through the upgrade, one just opens with tab crash, the other opens with oh snap.  Will probably reinstall both after firefox is fixed.

Firefox has been working well for the last two months for what I wanted it to open.  It is just the last couple of days that it thinks there is a proxy server it cannot reach.

Not sure if it matters, but I am using the Unity desktop, instead of grome.

I have reinstalled opera as a snap and it is working.